# iOS collectionView.sizeForItemAtIndexPath Breaks On Anything Before iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, collectionview

I am brand new to iOS development and I am trying to port a project I have on Android to iOS. I am trying to construct a collectionView in code as part of the implementation. The thing is as the data in each cell in the collection view can be different string sizes each cell *can* be a different size to it's neighbour. I am experimenting with the attached code but I have noticed that with an iPhone 6 either a physical device or in the simulator the UI looks as expected..anything else it looks horribly broken. It seems to be the sizeForIndexItemAtPath that is breaking it. Any ideas anyone? TIA

```
  import UIKit

  class ViewController: UIViewController,       UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    var thisCellHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height

        var thisWidth = screenWidth - 10

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 70, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: thisWidth, height: 120)
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        //collectionView!.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView!.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor("#15ADFF")
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 14
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        var typeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 0, 200, 21))
        typeLabel.text = "Card Type"
        typeLabel.font = typeLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)
        cell.addSubview(typeLabel)

        var titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 25, 300, 21))

        titleLabel.text = "This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title. This Is The Article Title."
        titleLabel.font = titleLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        titleLabel.sizeToFit()
        self.thisCellHeight = CGFloat(titleLabel.frame.height)
        println("The title text is \(self.thisCellHeight) high")
        cell.addSubview(titleLabel)

        var authorLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, thisCellHeight + 30, 200, 21))
        authorLabel.text = "This Is The Article Author"
        authorLabel.font = authorLabel.font.fontWithSize(15)
        cell.addSubview(authorLabel)

        var timestampLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, thisCellHeight + 50, 200, 21))
        timestampLabel.text = "This Is The Timestamp"
        timestampLabel.font = timestampLabel.font.fontWithSize(15)
        cell.addSubview(timestampLabel)

        return cell
    }

    func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
        var cString:String = hex.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet() as NSCharacterSet).uppercaseString

        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString = cString.substringFromIndex(advance(cString.startIndex, 1))
        }

        if (countElements(cString) != 6) {
            return UIColor.grayColor()
        }

        var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
        NSScanner(string: cString).scanHexInt(&rgbValue)

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {


        return CGSizeMake(320, 350)


    }



}
```

Comment: Can you explain (perhaps screenshots) of what you expect vs. what you see?

Comment: Well would you believe it... I was working on this late last night and gave up for the day. I just opened Xcode to take the screenshots and the code is now working...

Comment: I fixed it while you were sleeping. I wrote that comment to prompt you to open Xcode.

Comment: I don't understand - how was this fixed? By opening and closing xCode?

Answer (score 9):

You're setting the item size on the layout to be :

```
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: thisWidth, height: 120)
```

And you're also using the delegate method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(320, 350)
}
```

The first is being overridden by the second. `layout.itemSize` is the default size for each item, if the delegate method `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` isn't overridden. You're overriding the `layout.itemSize` with something which looks to be completely different. Try just removing the delegate function `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`, does this do what you expect?